# Prove inequality$\sum\limits_{n|i+j+k}x_{i}y_{j}z_{k}\le n^2$

Tags: inequality

Being given an integer $n\ge 2$, and $x_{i},y_{i},z_{i}\in \mathbb{R}$ ($i=1,2,\cdots,n$) such that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x^3_{i}+y^3_{i}+z^3_{i})=3n$$
show that
$$\sum_{i+j+k=n}x_{i}y_{j}z_{k}\le n^2.$$

I know  $a^3+b^3+c^3\ge 3abc$ if $a+b+c\ge 0$.

Comment: Do you mean $x_i y_j z_k$? Or $x_i, y_i, z_i \ge 0$? Otherwise $x_i$ can be arbitrarily large and the statement is obviously wrong.

Comment: Do you have the constraint $x_i, y_i, z_i \ge 0$?

Comment: sorry, Now I have edit, it's $x_{i}y_{j}z_{k}$,and this are real numbers

Comment: Does the verticle bar in $\sum_{n|i+j+k}x_{i}y_{j}z_{k}\le n^2$ mean "=" ?

Comment: @Andreas, is it not that $i+j+k$ is a multiple of $n$ ?

Comment: @communnites : $n=2$ is not possible or the trivial case and $x_{n-1}$,$x_{n}$,$y_{n-1}$,$y_{n}$,$z_{n-1}$,$z_{n}$ are not part of the second sum. Is this correct, no mistake in the question ?

Comment: @rrogers In standard notation, $n|i+j+k$ would mean "$n$ divides $i+j+k$", i.e. $i+j+k$ is an integer multiple of $n$.

Comment: @andre You're right, I wrote this again to avoid confusion.

Comment: @communnites Yor headline asks for the sum with condition $n|i+j+k$, and the main question body asks for the sum with condition $n=i+j+k$. Please make this consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume $x_i\geq 0$ start with $3x_i y_j z_k \leq x_i^3+ y_j^3+ z_k^3$.

Sum this over the triples $i,j,k$.  You get 
$$3 \textrm{LHS}\leq \sum_i x_i^3\sum_{j+k=n-i} 1 + \textrm{sums for }y_i,z_i.$$

The key idea is the combinatorics here: counting how many times the term $x_i^3$ arises.  The conclusion is that
$$3 \textrm{LHS}\leq \sum_i (n-i-1)(x_i^3+ y_i^3+ z_i^3)$$.

Now apply the hypothesis and you should be done.